# Python 3.6.4 - Is PIP Bundled?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pip

I downloaded Python 3.6.4 through a Linux package manager and the PIP command is not recognized.  Is PIP bundled with Python 3.6.4?

I am having problems running the get-pip.py script as I am running out of memory.  So I am looking to get PIP through other ways.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: you can get pip or pip3 from your package manager. It is interesting that you are running out of memory just running get-pip.py. What platform are you on (hardware) and what is your memory (RAM) size?

Comment: The hardware is Arduino Yun rev2.  It has 16 MB of flash memory.  But I expanded it with a micro Sd card of 8 GB.  I now have pip3 through the package manager but it runs out of memory downloading Flask.  Is flask available as a linux package outside of pip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard distribution of Python includes pip, but Linux packages are not the same as the standard distribution. Many Linux python packages do not include pip (or other things in the standard distribution, like IDLE or turtle). This can be useful for Linux systems that only need Python to run scripts, rather than for development.

Try installing pip separately with your package manager. It's usually available when Python is, but may be a separate package.

You can also try downloading the standard source distribution from python.org (you'd have to compile it), or depending on your needs, you could use an installer from a more complete distribution like [Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/).